# Как в адаптере удалить ImageView?

Tags: android, изображения

Делаю элемент для `RecyclerView` в котором в зависимости от пункта будет светится та или иная `ImageView`. Но столкнулся с проблемой если я пишу

```
holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
или 
holder.image.setImageDrawable(null); 
или 
holder.image.setMaxHeigh(0);
```

На месте там где `ImageView` стоит которую я пытаюсь скрыть пустое место размером с невидимую `ImageView`.

Вот разметка

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_facebook"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_instagram"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_telegram"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_vk"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_twitter"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/rec_viber"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Код адаптера

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter_Recomend extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter_Recomend.ViewHolder> {

    private Context c;
    private ArrayList<String> name, text_rec, l_facebook, l_instagram, l_telegram, l_vk, l_twitter, l_viber, logo;

    public RecycleViewAdapter_Recomend(Context c, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> text_rec, ArrayList<String> l_facebook, ArrayList<String> l_instagram, ArrayList<String> l_telegram, ArrayList<String> l_vk, ArrayList<String> l_twitter, ArrayList<String> l_viber, ArrayList<String> logo) {
        this.c = c;
        this.name = name;
        this.text_rec = text_rec;
        this.l_facebook = l_facebook;
        this.l_instagram = l_instagram;
        this.l_telegram = l_telegram;
        this.l_vk = l_vk;
        this.l_twitter = l_twitter;
        this.l_viber = l_viber;
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec, viewGroup,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecycleViewAdapter_Recomend.ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.color.bg)
                .error(R.color.bg)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);
        Glide.with(c)
                .asBitmap().apply(options)
                .load(logo.get(i))
                .into(holder.logo);
        try{
            holder.facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_facebook.get(i)));
                        c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.instagram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_instagram.get(i)));
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.telegram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_telegram.get(i)));
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_twitter.get(i)));
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.viber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_viber.get(i)));
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.vk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(l_vk.get(i)));
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.facebook.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook);
        holder.instagram.setImageResource(R.drawable.instagram);
        holder.telegram.setImageResource(R.drawable.telegram);
        holder.twitter.setImageResource(R.drawable.twitter);
        holder.vk.setImageResource(R.drawable.vk);
        holder.viber.setImageResource(R.drawable.viber);
        holder.
        switch (i+1){
            case 1://Progress

                holder.twitter.setImageDrawable(null);
                break;
        }
        holder.text_rec.setHtml(text_rec.get(i));
        holder.title.setText(name.get(i));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView rec;
        ImageView logo, facebook, instagram, telegram, twitter, viber, vk;
        TextView title;
        HtmlTextView text_rec;
        LinearLayout container;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View i) {
            super(i);
            rec = i.findViewById(R.id.rec);
            logo = i.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            facebook = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_facebook);
            instagram = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_instagram);
            telegram = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_telegram);
            twitter = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_twitter);
            viber = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_viber);
            vk = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_vk);
            text_rec = i.findViewById(R.id.html_rec);
            title = i.findViewById(R.id.name_rec);
            container = i.findViewById(R.id.rec_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да все уже пробовал. Просто забыл написать

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko добавил код адаптера

Comment: Здесь я скрываю не нужные мне картинки в соотвествии от позиции элементов

Comment: во-первых - я бы сделал скрывание картинок в самом начале, еще до того как будут присвоены сами ресурсы изображений, а во-вторых - holder. это опечатка и тут ничего не должно быть, или это ваша конструкция какая-то?

Comment: Это моя конструкция. Вы можете решить проблему пустого места между картинками?

Comment: я хочу решить эту проблему, но для того чтобы ее решить мне нужно понимать что у вас происходит)) поэтому я и задаю возможно глупые вопросы

Comment: Смотрите у меня ест елемент списка который имеет заголовок (name) описание (text_rec) логотип(logo) и 6 соц сетей при нажатии на которые переходит в одну из них. Но не все элементы списка имеют все 6 соц сетей некоторые 4 некоторые - 2. Мне нужнг скрыть не нужные соц сети. Вот я и использую даную конструкцию. Но когда я их скрываю у меня остается пустое место которое не очень красиво.

Comment: есть идея - уберите тег инвизибл из xml и устанавливайте это значение из адаптера, но инвизибл делает вью просто невидимым а место остается, а вам лучше использовать gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо View.INVISIBLE используйте View.GONE - он удаляет представление из разметки, а INVISIBLE только скрывает

Comment: я уже писал выше что пробовал тег gone в xml разметке. не помогает вовсе.

Comment: Извините не првильно Вас понял, я все делал в разметке хмл а нужно было в адаптере ставить Gone